# cy.task() with require('oracledb') throwing error

Tags: node.js, oracle, macos, cypress, node-oracledb

Installed:
"cypress": "^4.10.0"
"oracledb": "^5.0.0"

Node Oracle Client v5

$ node -v
v12.18.2

I'm getting the following error when I require node-oracle in cypress:
not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.

Anyone overcome this already?

Test code:

```
describe('DB Registration', () => {
    it.only('Register a new user', () => {
        cy.task('registration', emailAddress)
    })
})
```

plugins/index.js code

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
      'registration': () => {

    const oracledb = require('oracledb');
    try {
      oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: './instantclient_19_3'});
      
      console.log("IM INSIDE")

        let result;
        let connection;

        try {
            connection = oracledb.getConnection(  {
            user          : process.env.ORACLEDB_USER,
            password      : process.env.ORACLEDB_PASSWORD,
            connectString : "localhost/abc"
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got past this error by running `sudo spctl --master-disable` on the node oracle instantclient_19_3 folder. [Source](https://www.imore.com/how-open-apps-anywhere-macos-catalina-and-mojave).

Then in cypress.json i set `"nodeVersion": "system"` [Source](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/4436).

Comment: Now that Instant Client DMG 19.8 packages are signed, the `spctl` call may not be needed. Can a Cypress user confirm?